# auto update port list in python

Tags: python, tkinter, port

I want to create a user interface with tkinter and it includes reading serial ports.
I use code like this

```
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import serial
import sys
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()
window.title("test cell")

ports=list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())

selected=StringVar(window)
m_select=Combobox(window,textvariable=selected)
m_select['values']=ports
m_select['state']='readonly'
m_select.place(x=0,y=0)
window.mainloop()
```

in this case I can read all connected devices but if I connect or disconnect a new device I can not see it and I have to close the file and run it again.
is there any way that I could refresh it automatically and do not need to close it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below example to update the list inside the combobox when the down arrow is clicked.

I've tested this with a dummy function that returns a random number of com ports but this should work the same with the `serial.tools.comports` function.
(You'll need to comment back in lines that you require, I don't have serial on this PC)

```
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
#import serial
import sys
#import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from tkinter import *

def comports():
    """Dummy function, remove me for the real thing"""
    import random
    ports = [f"COM{i}" for i in range(random.randint(1,10))]
    return ports

def updateComPortList():
    #ports=list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    ports = comports()
    m_select['values']=ports

window=Tk()
window.title("test cell")

selected=StringVar(window)
m_select=Combobox(window,textvariable=selected,postcommand = updateComPortList)
m_select['state']='readonly'
m_select.place(x=0,y=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Mehrdadkh Excellent. Mark the question as answered if you are happy.